# SQL- pad results with extra rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a group of records that have a "Store" column. I need to basically split the result sets into groups of 13 records, creating blank rows to pad out each store to have 13 rows.
For simplicity, lets say I need groups of 4 records.

Example, given the below table:

```
-----------------
Store      Name
-----------------
A          John
A          Bill
B          Sam
C          James
C          Tim
C          Chris
D          Simon
D          Phil
```

I need the results to look like:

```
-----------------
Store      Name
-----------------
A          John
A          Bill
A
B          Sam
B
B
C          James
C          Tim
C          Chris
D          Simon
D          Phil
D
```

Is this at all possible with pure SQL? There are never going to be more than 3 rows for each store.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/354df)

Comment: i would use php to do the job

Comment: This is for a report so not possible

Comment: You say 13 rows and groups of 4, but then you show 12 rows and groups of 3. Could you please clarify?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? My query only works in SQL 2008 and up, but it can be adapted to SQL 2005 and up. It seems you have at least 2005... could you edit the tags on your question to add the exact version? `sql-server-2005` or `sql-server-2008` or `sql-server-2012`.

Comment: What is your reporting platform,  please? SSRS? What is the format of the data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one -

**DDL:**

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      Store CHAR(1)
    , Name VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #temp (Store, Name)
VALUES 
    ('A', 'John'),  ('A', 'Bill'),
    ('B', 'Sam'),   ('C', 'James'),
    ('C', 'Tim'),   ('C', 'Chris'),
    ('D', 'Simon'), ('D', 'Phil')
```

**Queries:**

***DevArt #1:***

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
          Store
        , Name
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
    FROM #temp
)
SELECT t.Store, Name = ISNULL(t3.Name, '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Store 
    FROM cte
) t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT rn = 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) t2
LEFT JOIN cte t3 ON t2.rn = t3.rn AND t.Store = t3.Store
```

***DevArt #2:***

```
SELECT t2.Store, Name = ISNULL(t3.Name, '')
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT Store, r = COUNT(1)
        FROM #temp
        GROUP BY Store
    ) t
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES (r), (r+1), (r+2)
    ) t2 (x)
) t2
LEFT JOIN #temp t3 ON t2.Store = t3.Store AND t2.x = t2.r
WHERE t2.x < 4
```

***Alexander Fedorenko:***

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Store
    FROM #temp
)  
SELECT o.Store, o.name
FROM cte s 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 3 x.Store, x.name
    FROM (
        SELECT s2.Store, s2.name
        FROM #temp s2
        WHERE s.Store = s2.Store
        UNION ALL
        SELECT s.Store, ''
        UNION ALL
        SELECT s.Store, ''
    ) x
) o
```

***ErikE:***

```
SELECT Store, Name
FROM (
   SELECT 
          x.Store
        , x.Name
        , s = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x.Store ORDER BY x.s)
   FROM #temp t
   CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES 
            (Store, Name, 0), 
            (Store, '', 1), 
            (Store, '', 1)
   ) x (Store, Name, S)
) z
WHERE s <= 3
ORDER BY Store
```

***AmitSingh:***

```
SELECT t.Store, Name = COALESCE(
    (
        SELECT name
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                  row1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY Store) 
                , *
            FROM #temp
        ) c
        WHERE t.[row] = c.row1
            AND t.Store = c.Store
    )
    , '') 
FROM
(
    SELECT
          [Row] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Store ORDER BY a.Store) 
        , a.Store
    FROM (
        SELECT Store
        FROM #temp
        GROUP BY Store
    ) a
    , (
        SELECT TOP 3 Store
        FROM #temp
    ) b
) t
```

***Andriy M #1:***

```
;WITH ranked AS 
(
     SELECT
            Store
          , Name
          , rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY 1/0)
     FROM #temp
)
, pivoted AS 
(
     SELECT
            Store
          , [1] = ISNULL([1], '')
          , [2] = ISNULL([2], '')
          , [3] = ISNULL([3], '')
     FROM ranked
     PIVOT (
          MAX(Name) 
          FOR rnk IN ([1], [2], [3])
     ) p
)
, unpivoted AS 
(
     SELECT
            Store
          , Name
     FROM pivoted
     UNPIVOT (
          Name FOR rnk IN ([1], [2], [3])
     ) u
)
SELECT *
FROM unpivoted
```

***Andriy M #2:***

```
;WITH ranked AS 
(
     SELECT
            Store
          , Name
          , rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY 1/0)
     FROM #temp
)
, padded AS 
(
     SELECT
            Store
          , Name
     FROM ranked
     PIVOT (
          MAX(Name) 
          FOR rnk IN ([1], [2], [3])
     ) p
     CROSS APPLY (
          VALUES
               (ISNULL([1], '')),
               (ISNULL([2], '')),
               (ISNULL([3], ''))
     ) x (Name)
)
SELECT *
FROM padded
```

**Output:**

```
Store Name
----- ----------
A     John
A     Bill
A     
B     Sam
B     
B     
C     James
C     Tim
C     Chris
D     Simon
D     Phil
D
```

**Statistics:**

```
    Query Presenter  Scans  Logical Reads
-------------------  -----  -------------
          DevArt #1    3     41
          DevArt #2    2      9
Alexander Fedorenko    4      5
              ErikE    1      1
          AmitSingh   22     25
        Andriy M #1    1      1
        Andriy M #2    1      1
```

**Query cost:**

[image: Query cost]

**Extended statistics:**

[image: ExStat]

**Execution statistics:**

[image: ExecStat]

**Query plan (from dbForge Studio for MS SQL):**

[image: Query plan]

Comment: Would `SELECT DISTINCT Store FROM cte` better be done as `SELECT DISTINCT Store FROM @temp`--to express to the developer reading the query that you don't actually care about the CTE's output at this point? Also, `t3` isn't needed--you can collapse it with the query elements in the outermost query.

Comment: @ErikE, thanks for the comment. In this case `SELECT DISTINCT Store FROM cte` and `SELECT DISTINCT Store FROM @temp` are equal.

Comment: @Devart I understand they are equal to the engine, my observation was that they are not equal "to the developer reading the query", who has to examine the CTE an additional, unnecessary time to see why. I think it expresses the intent more simply to use `@temp` there. Any thoughts on combining the outer query with the contents of `t3`?

Answer (score 4):

```
Select t.store_id,Coalesce((Select Name from (
 Select row_Number() Over(Partition by store_id order by store_id) as row1, * from stores)c
 where t.row=c.row1 and t.store_id=c.store_id),'') as cfgg
from
 (Select row_Number() Over(Partition by a.store_id order by a.store_id) as row, 
 a.store_id from 
 (Select store_id from stores group by store_id) a ,(Select top 3 store_id from stores)b
 ) t
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/354df/19)

Comment: Thanks. Works a treat. Although the performance is an issue here. Yours takes 38 seconds on my table whereas the one by @Devart is < 1 second. But thank you!

Comment: @Lock welcome....always...and sorry culdnot provide optmize query...anyway i m glad you found your result and optmize one...too

Comment: @AmitSingh your solution is too complex, but you tried to give a good answer. +1

Comment: @AmitSingh is most importantly to believe in yourself and you will succeed. Good luck.

Comment: @Devart yeah i m donig that...and learnig also from great answers like your's... not to only answer but provide some optmize query..after all optmize query is soul of db..gud luck too

Answer (score 4):

One more option with APPLY operator

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT store_id
  FROM stores
  GROUP BY store_id  
  )  
  SELECT o.store_id, o.name
  FROM cte s CROSS APPLY (
                          SELECT TOP 3 x.store_id, x.name
                          FROM (
                                SELECT s2.store_id, s2.name
                                FROM stores s2
                                WHERE s.store_id = s2.store_id
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT s.store_id, ''
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT s.store_id, ''                                 
                                ) x
                          ) o
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/354df/22)

Comment: Now that I've stared at this a bit, I noticed that you can do with one less `UNION ALL` in there...

Comment: Also I think the last `UNION ALL SELECT s.store_id, ''` is not required.

Comment: guys, is it safe to use TOP without an ORDER BY clause in this case? and the last UNION ALL removed. tnx @Devart

Comment: @Alexander Fedorenko, I didn't see any problems with it.

Comment: I was first with the `UNION ALL` note :-P  :)

Comment: Sorry @ErikE. You are the best;)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a query that works (SQL Server 2008 and up, can be fixed to work in 2005):

```
SELECT Store, Name
FROM (
   SELECT
      X.Store, X.Name, R = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY X.Store ORDER BY X.S)
   FROM
      @temp T
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES
         (Store, Name, 0), (Store, '', 1), (Store, '', 1)
      ) X (Store, Name, S)
) Z
WHERE R <= 3
ORDER BY Store
;
```

According to `SET STATISTICS IO ON;`, here are performance statistics (all have negligible CPU at this low number of rows, perhaps more rows would help determine the best performer):

```
    Query Presenter  Scans  Logical Reads
-------------------  -----  -------------
              ErikE    1      1
Alexander Fedorenko    4      5
             Devart    3     41
          AmitSingh   22     25
```

My query does not preserve the "original" ordering of the names for each store, however that is *not* a flaw because there is no concept of ordering in a relational database table. You *must* supply a column to order by if you want to preserve a particular sequence.

Comment: +1 - for the good answer. And also please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option, this time [using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx):

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    store_id,
    name,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY 1/0)
  FROM stores
),
pivoted AS (
  SELECT
    store_id,
    [1] = ISNULL([1], ''),
    [2] = ISNULL([2], ''),
    [3] = ISNULL([3], '')
  FROM ranked
  PIVOT (
    MAX(name) FOR rnk IN ([1], [2], [3])
  ) p
),
unpivoted AS (
  SELECT
    store_id,
    name
  FROM pivoted
  UNPIVOT (
    name FOR rnk IN ([1], [2], [3])
  ) u
)
SELECT *
FROM unpivoted
;
```

A SQL Fiddle demo to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/354df/39.

Note that the UNPIVOT step in the above query has to be done in a separate SELECT from the PIVOT action. That is because UNPIVOT does not generate rows where columns listed in the IN column list contain NULLs. However, you could replace UNPIVOT with an equivalent technique (like CROSS APPLY) and thus move the unpivoting to the same subquery that does the pivoting:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    store_id,
    name,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY 1/0)
  FROM stores
),
padded AS (
  SELECT
    store_id,
    name
  FROM ranked
  PIVOT (
    MAX(name) FOR rnk IN ([1], [2], [3])
  ) p
  CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES
      (ISNULL([1], '')),
      (ISNULL([2], '')),
      (ISNULL([3], ''))
  ) x (name)
)
SELECT *
FROM padded
;
```

A SQL Fiddle demo for the modified version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/354df/40.

Comment: yeah. is most elegant, smart and faster solution. Thanks for the present;) @Devart please add this solution

Comment: Thank you for the kind exaggeration. :) To be perfectly honest, I guess your clever idea of using TOP 3 was a hint, to a degree.