# Select from sql table, fill in non-existing entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two tables:

```
Rooms{ roomNum, maxOccupancy}

Reservations{Name, RoomNum}
```

I want to select all of the names from reservations with a given room number, but if the number of rows returned is less than maxOccupancy for that room number, I want to also return null (or "empty") rows for empty spots.

So I know I need to start with:

```
select Name from Reservations where Reservations.RoomNum=7 and Reservations.RoomNum = Rooms.roomNum
```

but there's a whole lot more to be done.

**Edit**

A sample dataset would be:

```
Rooms: roomNum, Max Occupancy:
         7    , 4

Reservations: Name, RoomNum:
              Me,    7 
              You,   7
```

So the result would be:

```
result: Name:
        Me
        You
        null (or "empty", I just need the row to exist)
        null
```

Comment: can we have sample data set ?

Comment: @Bingo, thank you for taking a look, I've added a sample dataset and what the desired end result would be.

Comment: The phrase you're looking for @NickO is Join. You need the join those tables togather.

Comment: What is your db? SQL server, mysql, oracle?

Comment: @unlimit SQL server.  @ Zane thanks!  I'm still a little stuck on the returning empty rows, but I'll update once I've got it.

Comment: @NickO I'm not going to lie I have no idea what you mean by empty rows...

Comment: @Zane, no problem, perhaps what I'm looking for isn't practical.  What I want, is the query to return a table with <code>MaxOccupancy</code> entries, where the entries contain the names of the people in the room, or null if all of the people have been listed already.

Comment: @Nick what is your application server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL- pad results with extra rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101574/sql-pad-results-with-extra-rows)

Comment: @AndriyM, It looks like you may be right.  I think my question might be a little more general purpose, but the question you reference can be modified to fit my needs.  Sorry I didn't see it before!  (and thanks again to everyone who helped me out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that is for Sql Server, the following query will be useful:

```
CREATE TABLE Reservations(
  Name VARCHAR(100),
  RoomNum INT
  )

CREATE TABLE Rooms(
  RoomNum INT,
  MaxSlots INT
  )

INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES(7,4)
INSERT INTO Reservations VALUES('ME',7)
INSERT INTO Reservations VALUES('YOU',7)

-- Here the query!!
WITH temp ( n ) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 + n FROM temp WHERE n < 100
)

SELECT t.n AS slot, reserv.Name, a.RoomNum
FROM Rooms a
INNER JOIN temp t ON t.n <= a.MaxSlots
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT r.Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY r.NAME) AS SlotNumber
  FROM Reservations r
  ) reserv ON reserv.SlotNumber = t.n
```

You can try this **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2578/5)**.

**Note: Be careful should always be, n < 100.**

**(EDITED 2013-07-14)**
Here the solution a little more generic, works perfectly wiht more than one room reservation:

```
WITH temp1 ( n ) AS (
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 + n FROM temp1 WHERE n < 100
), temp2 AS (
  SELECT 
  x.RoomNum,
  x.Name,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY x.RoomNum ORDER BY x.RoomNum,x.Name) AS ROWNUM
  FROM Reservations x
)

SELECT a.RoomNum, t1.n AS slot, t2.Name
FROM Rooms a
INNER JOIN temp1 t1 ON t1.n <= a.MaxSlots
LEFT JOIN temp2 t2 ON t2.ROWNUM = t1.n AND a.RoomNum = t2.RoomNum
ORDER BY a.RoomNum,t1.n,t2.Name
```

You can try this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e0fb/92).

Comment: I may be confused, but is this working?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e0fb/2  I added some more data, and it seems to cross the data together.

Comment: @nickO you're right, this query only useful for your example...I'm thinking other a litlle more generic

Comment: ohh this was the case, never used `WITH` and was trying to understand your query and I wasn't getting it, seems will have to read it again :)

Comment: @Everyone Thank you very much for your help!  I'm still messing around with this solution idea, but by and large, it is getting me very close to what I want (plus that sqlfiddle thing is nifty)

Comment: @NickO sorry for the delay, but i think i could create a query that you need. Please see this **[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e0fb/92)**.

Comment: @GastonF. The last link was perfect and exactly what I needed!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I tried this out with dynamic sql. I don't know if you want to use dynamic sql. But here it goes:

```
-- creating temp tables, you will have your own tables
create table #room (room int, mo int)
create table #reservations (name varchar(100), room int)

declare @diff as int
declare @max as int
declare @i as int

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

insert into #room values (7, 4)

insert into #reservations values ('Me', 7)
insert into #reservations values ('You', 7)

--get the max occupancy of the room
Select @max = mo from #room where room = 7
--get the diff
Select @diff = @max - COUNT(*) from #reservations where room = 7

set @i = 1
set @sql = ''


if @max > @diff 
begin        
    -- we want to generate (Select '' union all) for the difference
while @i <= @diff
  begin
   set @sql = @sql + 'Select ''''' + ' union all '
   set @i = @i + 1
  end
end

--chop off the 'union all' at the end
set @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, len(@sql) - 8)
set @sql = 'Select name from #reservations union all ' + @sql
--select @sql 

execute sp_executesql @sql

drop table #room
drop table #reservations
```

In the script above the sql generated is `Select name from #reservations union all Select '' union all Select ''`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that is not quite as streamlined as some of the others, but nothing has to be hard coded or limited. It will generate your table of room nums with max occupancies and then fill in the names of those with reservations.

```
/* create your test data */
CREATE TABLE #reservations (Person varchar(50), RoomNum INT)
INSERT INTO #reservations (Person, RoomNum)
VALUES ('Me', '7'),
('You', '7' ),
('Boo', '10'),
('Beyonce', '12')

CREATE TABLE #Rooms (Ulink INT, RoomNum INT, MaxOccupancy INT)
INSERT INTO #Rooms (ULink, RoomNum, MaxOccupancy)
VALUES ('1', '7', '4'),
('2', '10', '2'),
('3', '12', '7')


/* create the final table to be populated */
CREATE TABLE #ResultTable (ULink INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name varchar(50), RoomNum INT)

/* run two cursors to generate all rows and then populate. This could be nested */

DECLARE @roomNum INT
DECLARE @mark INT
DECLARE D_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT RoomNum FROM #Rooms
Open D_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM D_cursor INTO @roomNum
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @mark = (select maxOccupancy FROM #Rooms WHERE RoomNum = @roomNum)
    DECLARE @loop INT
    SET @loop = 1
    WHILE @loop <= @mark
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #ResultTable (RoomNum) SELECT RoomNum FROM #Rooms WHERE         RoomNum = @roomNum
            SET @loop = @loop + 1
        END
    FETCH NEXT FROM D_cursor INTO @roomNum
END
CLOSE D_cursor
DEALLOCATE D_cursor

/* second cursor updates */
DECLARE @person Varchar(50)
DECLARE @roomNumB INT
DECLARE @ULink INT
DECLARE D_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT Person, RoomNum  FROM #Reservations
Open D_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM D_cursor INTO @person, @RoomNumB
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

UPDATE #ResultTable 
SET Name = @person 
WHERE RoomNum = @roomNumB 
AND ULink = (SELECT TOP 1 ULink FROM #ResultTable WHERE RoomNum = @roomNumB AND Name IS     NULL ORDER BY ULink ASC)

FETCH NEXT FROM D_Cursor INTO @person, @roomNumB
END
CLOSE D_cursor
DEALLOCATE D_cursor

SELECT * FROM #ResultTable  --This is here to view it all
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using a recursive CTE:

```
/* define sample data */
DECLARE @Rooms TABLE
    (
      Room INT ,
      MaxOccupancy INT
    )
DECLARE @Reservations TABLE
    (
      Room INT ,
      NAME VARCHAR(100)
    ) 

INSERT  INTO @Rooms
VALUES  ( 7, 4 )
INSERT  INTO @Reservations
        ( Room, NAME )
VALUES  ( 7, 'ME' ),
        ( 7, 'YOU' );


/*Uses recursive CTE to build a tally table; hardcoded maximum of 10
  Uses a Row_Number() function to order the slots in a given reservation per room
*/

WITH    N AS ( SELECT   num = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   num + 1
               FROM     N
               WHERE    num < 10 /*hardcoded maximum of 10*/
             )
    SELECT  r2.name
    FROM    @Rooms r
            CROSS JOIN N
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  Room ,
                                Name ,
                                rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Room ORDER BY name )
                        FROM    @Reservations
                      ) r2 ON r.Room = r2.Room
                              AND n.num = r2.rn
    WHERE   N.num <= r.MaxOccupancy
```

Comment: I'm still checking things out, but this answer is more in line with what I recall from database class years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 0
create table #empty (name char(2));
WHILE (select MaxOccupancy - (select count(*) from Reservations where roomNum = 7) from Rooms where roomNum = 7) > @count
BEGIN
   insert into #empty select '  '
   SET @count = (@count + 1)
END
select Name
from Reservations
where roomNum = 7
UNION ALL
select Name
from #empty
drop table #empty;
```