# SQL Server - Select a full dataset for every possible column combination

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's a question I've been trying to answer for quite some time.  It's been difficult, so please forgive the long text.

I have an MS SQL Server database with a table corresponding to worldwide regions by name.  There's another table with the datacenters that reside in each region.  In another table there is a list of environments (DEV, PROD, etc) that run in each datacenter.  In another, a listing of virtual machine "types" that run in each environment.  Finally, in another table I have a list of virtual machines in various dated stages of "approval" for deployment.

Some examples of vm "types" could include tags like "small", "medium", and "large".

I'd like to create a select statement that returns rows with all possible combinations within that family of relationships, regardless of whether or not a given virtual machine type actually exists in the data.

For every:
    month from last year until next year -> show count of approved/unapproved VM's -> per virtual machine "type", per environment, per datacenter, per region ---> even if zero/null

As suggested in this answer: [SQL- pad results with extra rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101574/sql-pad-results-with-extra-rows) I've been using tricks like UNPIVOT and OUTER/CROSS APPLY, but to no avail, because I'm not merely trying to get a two dimensional result.  In my case there are five.

Tables and Data (this has been simplified):

```
USE [infra]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[datacenter](
   [datacenter_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [region_id] [int] NULL,
   [datacenter] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[env](
   [env_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [env] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[region](
   [region_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [region] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vm_class](
   [vm_class_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [vm_class] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[virtual_machine](
   [virtual_machine_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [hostname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
   [region] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
   [datacenter] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
   [env] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
   [approval_status] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
   [deployment_month] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[datacenter] ON

GO
INSERT [dbo].[datacenter] ([datacenter_id], [region_id], [datacenter]) VALUES (1, 1, N'Datacenter A')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[datacenter] ([datacenter_id], [region_id], [datacenter]) VALUES (2, 2, N'Datacenter B')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[datacenter] ([datacenter_id], [region_id], [datacenter]) VALUES (3, 3, N'Datacenter C')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[datacenter] ([datacenter_id], [region_id], [datacenter]) VALUES (4, 4, N'Datacenter D')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[datacenter] ([datacenter_id], [region_id], [datacenter]) VALUES (5, 1, N'Datacenter E')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[datacenter] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[env] ON

GO
INSERT [dbo].[env] ([env_id], [env]) VALUES (1, N'LAB')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[env] ([env_id], [env]) VALUES (2, N'DEV')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[env] ([env_id], [env]) VALUES (3, N'QA')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[env] ([env_id], [env]) VALUES (4, N'COB')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[env] ([env_id], [env]) VALUES (5, N'PROD')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[env] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[region] ON

GO
INSERT [dbo].[region] ([region_id], [region]) VALUES (1, N'EUR')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[region] ([region_id], [region]) VALUES (2, N'APAC')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[region] ([region_id], [region]) VALUES (3, N'NAM')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[region] ([region_id], [region]) VALUES (4, N'LATAM')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[region] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[vm_class] ON

GO
INSERT [dbo].[vm_class] ([vm_class_id], [vm_class]) VALUES (1, N'SMALL')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[vm_class] ([vm_class_id], [vm_class]) VALUES (2, N'MEDIUM')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[vm_class] ([vm_class_id], [vm_class]) VALUES (3, N'LARGE')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[vm_class] ([vm_class_id], [vm_class]) VALUES (4, N'ELASTIC')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[vm_class] OFF
GO
```

Here's the SQL I've written so far, which doesn't return a complete dataset (there are "missing" rows where I'd expect NULLs).

```
SELECT
    all_dates.unpivoted_date,
    r.region,
    d.datacenter,
    e.env,
    v.vm_class,
    ISNULL(SUM(virtual_machine), 0) AS [vm count]
FROM vmachines vms
FULL OUTER JOIN region r ON r.region = vms.region
FULL OUTER JOIN datacenter d on d.datacenter = vms.dc_label_final
FULL OUTER JOIN env e on e.env = fcast.env
FULL OUTER JOIN vm_class v on v.vm_class = vms.vm_class
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT CONVERT( DATE, mapped_date ) AS unpivoted_date FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DATEADD( MONTH, -13, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_12,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -12, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_11,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -11, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_10,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -10, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_09,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -9, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_08,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -8, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_07,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -7, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_06,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -6, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_05,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -5, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_04,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -4, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_03,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -3, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_02,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -2, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_01,
            DATEADD( MONTH, -1, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_00,
            DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) m_01,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 1, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_02,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 2, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_03,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 3, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_04,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 4, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_05,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 5, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_06,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 6, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_07,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 7, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_08,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 8, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_09,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 9, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_10,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 10, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_11,
            DATEADD( MONTH, 11, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_12
    ) pvt
    UNPIVOT
    (
        mapped_date FOR date_item IN
        (
            mp_12,          mp_11,          mp_10,          mp_09,
            mp_08,          mp_07,          mp_06,          mp_05,
            mp_04,          mp_03,          mp_02,          mp_01,
            m_00,           m_01,           m_02,           m_03,
            m_04,           m_05,           m_06,           m_07,
            m_08,           m_09,           m_10,           m_11,
            m_12
        )
    ) AS wd
) all_dates ON all_dates.unpivoted_date = CONVERT( DATE, vms.approval_month )
WHERE unpivoted_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    all_dates.unpivoted_date,
    r.region,
    d.datacenter,
    e.env, 
    v.vm_class
ORDER BY
    all_dates.unpivoted_date,
    r.region,
    d.datacenter,
    e.env,
    v.vm_class
```

Comment: Please provide definition of each tables and some data to work with. thanks

Comment: Using cross join is getting me closer (I'm continuing to work on this).  It works until I join the final virtual machines table.  If I don't specify enough matching criteria for the join, the sums are inaccurate and the query takes many seconds.  However, if I am specific in the join critera for the VM table, I literally get the exact same resultset I get when not using cross-join.

Comment: Cross joining, depending on the size of your tables, will give you an immense results set.  If you even had 100 rows in each of those tables, you'd be computing a table with 100*100*100*100*100 rows, or 10,000,000,000 rows.  It's technically correct that you're asking to do that, yes - but consider whether you want that immense of a cartesian product, really.

Comment: @KashifQureshi I added the table definitions above in an update to the question

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet it looks like the trick was to cross join only the tables where I needed a full data matrix, and segregate it into an aliased subselect.  Then and only then could I join the massive virtual machines table to that aliased subselect, and get the "full set of possible combinations" that I needed, without getting the huge cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are joining the [vmachines] table against your approval_month date criteria, and that will remove all records from the results where a paticular region/datacenter/class combo does not have an existing vmachines record.

Try a simplified version of your query without the date information to verify that without the date join, full records are returned.

```
SELECT
    r.region,
    d.datacenter,
    e.env,
    v.vm_class,
    ISNULL(SUM(virtual_machine), 0) AS [vm count]
FROM vmachines vms
FULL OUTER JOIN region r ON r.region = vms.region
FULL OUTER JOIN datacenter d on d.datacenter = vms.dc_label_final
FULL OUTER JOIN env e on e.env = fcast.env
FULL OUTER JOIN vm_class v on v.vm_class = vms.vm_class
GROUP BY r.region, d.datacenter, e.env, v.vm_class
```

As a solution, consider creating a user function that converts the approval_month to a desired month category to include in the SELECT and GROUP BY.

```
select
    .....
    dbo.ApprovalMonth(vms.approval_month) as appmonth
GROUP BY .....,  appmonth
```

The function can return NULL when the approval date value is NULL  (where there is no matching region/datacenter/class combination) or return a string of your choice.

Comment: I was able to get the results I needed.  Unfortunately I'm not in control of the virtual machines table, so it can't be normalized and has to be joined on text columns.  The solution was a cross-joined (outer apply) dataset that also involved the use of unpivot.  It is completely encapsulated as a subquery, then joined to the virtual machines table.  The query won't fit in this comment :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL code that worked for me (A combination of cross joins, unpivots, and subqueries):

```
SELECT xjoin.*,
COUNT(virtual_machine.*) AS [vm count]
-- and I also added a few more aggregate functions here --
FROM
(
    SELECT
        r.region,
        d.datacenter,
        e.env,
        v.vm_class,
        all_dates.unpivoted_date
    FROM region r
    CROSS JOIN datacenter d
    CROSS JOIN env e
    CROSS JOIN vm_class v
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT CONVERT( DATE, mapped_date ) AS unpivoted_date FROM
        (
            SELECT
                DATEADD( MONTH, -13, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_12,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -12, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_11,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -11, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_10,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -10, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_09,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -9, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_08,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -8, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_07,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -7, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_06,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -6, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_05,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -5, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_04,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -4, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_03,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -3, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_02,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -2, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) mp_01,
                DATEADD( MONTH, -1, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_00,
                DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) m_01,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 1, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_02,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 2, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_03,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 3, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_04,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 4, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_05,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 5, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_06,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 6, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_07,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 7, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_08,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 8, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_09,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 9, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_10,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 10, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_11,
                DATEADD( MONTH, 11, ( DATEADD( DAY, 1, EOMONTH( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ) m_12
        ) pvt
        UNPIVOT
        (
            mapped_date FOR date_item IN
            (
                mp_12,          mp_11,          mp_10,          mp_09,
                mp_08,          mp_07,          mp_06,          mp_05,
                mp_04,          mp_03,          mp_02,          mp_01,
                m_00,           m_01,           m_02,           m_03,
                m_04,           m_05,           m_06,           m_07,
                m_08,           m_09,           m_10,           m_11,
                m_12
            )
        ) AS wd
    ) all_dates
) xjoin
FULL OUTER JOIN [virtual_machine] vm ON
    vm.deployment_month = xjoin.unpivoted_date
    AND vm.region = xjoin.region
    AND vm.datacenter = xjoin.datacenter
    AND vm.env = xjoin.env
    AND vm.vm_class = xjoin.vm_class
GROUP BY
    xjoin.region,
    xjoin.datacenter,
    xjoin.env,
    xjoin.vm_class,
    xjoin.unpivoted_date
ORDER BY
    region,
    datacenter,
    env,
    vm_class,
    unpivoted_date
```